# SQL: Getting null values on comparing current values to previous period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have copied this SQL query from another website and I'm not actually sure why it returns null values for the previous period and the month comparing it with. What should I adjust in the query to get the desired result?

SQL Query:

```
WITH monthly_metrics AS (
SELECT EXTRACT(year from day) as year,
     EXTRACT(month from day) as month,
       SUM(revenue) as revenue
  FROM daily_metrics
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT year AS current_year, 
       month AS current_month, 
       revenue AS revenue_current_month, 
       LAG(year,12) OVER ( ORDER BY year, month) AS previous_year, 
       LAG(month,12) OVER ( ORDER BY year, month) AS month_comparing_with,
       LAG(revenue,12) OVER ( ORDER BY year, month) AS revenue_12_months_ago,
       revenue - LAG(revenue,12) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) AS month_to_month_difference
FROM monthly_metrics
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Query Result:
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=854df9245453a5bc7312b0dfdf6a0da5)

Comment: Appreciate that the first year in your output will have no lag 12 month value, since no year came before it.  That explains why you see `NULL` for the first year.  Not sure if you are seeing null everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Using other IDE I am also getting null values for the succeeding period like 2020 and 2021

Comment: You need to enclose dates in single quotes otherwise mysql sees arithmetic where - is minus.. eg 2019-01-01 = 2017 voting to close as typo.

Comment: I can't say anymore without seeing some sample data.  I suggest you step through your query, starting with the CTE, to see if that works as expected.

Comment: @P.Salmon - added enclosure for the dates, thanks! however, the comparison rows are still returning null values

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen, checked it also and it runs well until I performed the comparison query

Comment: You need to play with your lag functions to get what you want eg lag(year,12) should probably be lag(year,1)..

Comment: @P.Salmon It makes sense, thanks! it works now